# How do I check if a variable contains at least one alphabetic character in Bash?

Tags: bash

The version of bash i use is 4.3.11 and I use 'mcedit' as my script writer. I want to check if a variable contains at least one alphabetical character such that 'harry33' and 'a1111' are deemed valid.

I've tried the code below in my script however an error is returned which states that there is an error with '[[:'

**SOLVED**

```
#name = "test123"
read -p "Enter you name: " name
until [[ "$name" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; do
    read -p "Please enter a valid name: " name
done
```

Comment: I think you need a space after your `[[`

Comment: Ben's right: `[[` is not mere syntax, it's essentially a *command* (it's actually a "reserved word" like if, case, while, ...) and as such, it needs whitespace to separate it from its arguments. Just like you need a space between `cat` and `filename`

Comment: I've added a space after the '[[' and it doesn't work. I still get an error returned.

Comment: Is the 'Za' in '[A-Za-z]' supposed to be highlighted in my script, causing if it does, it doesn't.

Comment: Your code as written above works for me. What is the specific error you are receiving?

Comment: @pythontamer Can't reproduce. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Ah ok, it works, sorry about that. My next question is how to put these 2 conditions in a while loop.

Comment: I would suggest that you create another question then that deals with that topic specifically.

Comment: Ok, will do, i will remove that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you wrote has a couple of issues with spaces (one you already corrected after the `[[`) and the spaces around an equal should **not** exist:

```
name="test123"
if [[ "$name" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; then
    echo "Please enter valid input: "
fi
```

The line: "Please enter valid input: " will be printed in this case.
As `$name` contains several values in the range `a-z`.

Maybe what you want is the opposite, that the line is printed if the variable contains characters **outside** the range:

```
name="test"
if [[ "$name" =~ [^A-Za-z] ]]; then
    echo "The input contains characters outside the a-z or A-Z range."
fi
```

But in this case, the characters accepted may include accented (international) characters like `é`, `è`, or `ë`. Which are `in-range` in several Language Collate sequences.

That also happens with `[^[:alpha:]]`.

Either you embrace full internationalization or limit yourself to old ASCII:

```
name="test"
LC_COLLATE=C
if [[ "$name" =~ [^A-Za-z] ]]; then
    echo "The input contains characters outside the a-z or A-Z range."
fi
```

---

If you want to have as valid names with Alpha and digits, there are two options. One which is very strict (old ASCII ranges):

```
name="harry33"
LC_COLLATE=C
if [[ "$name" =~ ^[0-9A-Za-z]+$ ]]; then
    echo "The input only contains digits and alpha."
fi
```

The other option will also allow `é`, `ß` or `đ`, etc. (which is perfectly fine for an internationalized name), and the range is defined either by the variable LC_COLLATE or LC_ALL as set in the environment.

```
name="harry33"
if [[ "$name" =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "The input only contains digits and alpha."
fi
```

This option will reject `$%&()` and similar.

Comment: The variable 'name' is just a comment, a test input.

Comment: As i've written in my question i want it such that 'harry33' and 'a1111' are deemed valid.

Comment: @pythontamer Answer edited as per your request. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The portable solution free of bashisms such as `[[` would be

```
case $name in
(*[a-zA-Z]*)
   echo "Yay! Got an alphabetic character."
   ;;
(*)
   echo "Hmm, no a-z or A-Z found."
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Could you please explain what each line does. I am not very familiar with 'care' or the asterisk symbols used, nor am I with 'esac'. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @pythontamer The case/esac is the shell construct to match a string against a set of alternatives, each of which is a glob pattern surrounded by parentheses and ended with a double semicolon. The asterisk matches zero or more characters. Think of it as an if/elif/else/fi on steroids.

Comment: Could you explain what a 'glob pattern' is and what do the double semi colons mean, please.

Comment: @pythontamer When string matching, the shell supports the glob patterns `*` for zero or more characters, `?` for exactly one character, and `[x-y]` for a range of characters or a character class. Some people call glob patterns *wild cards*. The double semicolon is the syntactic element to separate case/esac alternatives. This is all part of the shell grammar.

Comment: Thank you very much, however i am not that confident with these new functions. I will do further research into them in order to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

First, Bash is picky about spacing, so have a space after your test brackets [[ and ]]  Also, if you are looking for user names, I'd think you'd want it to start with a letter, and if it didn't, then echo your prompt.

```
if [[ ! $var =~ ^[[:alpha:]] ]]; then 
    echo -n "Please enter valid input: "
    read response
fi
```